# How to get VS Code to understand JSDOC's @typedef across multiple files

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I want to specify a type in one file, and be able to reuse it in another one. I tried [modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021085/is-it-possible-to-tell-jsdoc-to-look-in-a-file-separate-from-the-source-code-for) but it didn't work in VS Code. Is there any other solution? Just wanna have all types for my project to be reusable so I can reference them in different functions across files. [This is the closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183450/jsdoc-typedef-in-a-separate-file) I have found.

Answer (score 36):

I've had some success with using [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) and its [`include`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-the-include-property) property in a plain JavaScript project in Visual Studio Code 1.33.1

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Given the following JavaScript project:

```
src/
├── types/
|   ├── person.js
|   ├── question.js
|
├── answer.js
├── jsconfig.json
```

Where both `question.js` and `person.js` are type definitions:

*person.js*

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} Person
 * @property {string} firstName
 * @property {string} lastName
 */
```

*question.js*

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} Question
 * @property {Person} askedBy
 * @property {string} text
 */
```

And `answer.js` is a function that accepts a question and return an answer:

```js
/**
 * Takes a question and return an answer
 * @param {Question} question 
 */
function answer(question) {
  return 42;
}
```

As you can see in the first screencast I do get IntelliSense support when hovering over the `Question` type notation:

[image]

On top of that IntelliSense is also now able to offer code completion based on my types definitions:

[image]

Comment: There was in issued for this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25386. It was closed but I don't think they fixed it.

Comment: This works perfectly for my project and does not require use of "includes"

Answer (score 15):

[Since TypeScript 2.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377#issuecomment-379935736) which is embedded in the newer VS Codes, it is possible by using the `import` syntax in JSDoc, like so

```
/**
 * @typedef {import("koa").Context} Context
 *
 * @typedef {Object} BodyparserOptions
 * @prop {(ctx: Context) => boolean} [detectJSON] Custom json request detect function. Default `null`.
 */
```

Also VS Code should be picking up all types defined across the workspace.

Comment: If you do this in a lot of files, you'll end up with a big list of `Context` typedefs. Every time you try to import `Context`, autocomplete will show this list and it's not clear which one to pick :(

Comment: @Jespertheend True, but how is that different from importing code? In the end, the path to `Context` determines which one we mean. Alternatively you would have to use unique names for your various `Context` types. I believe the alternative is more cumbersome.

Comment: The difference is that when you import code it doesn't get exported automatically. I don't think there's any good way to work around this at the moment. There's an open ticket for this here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46011