# How to type hint class definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, jsdoc

Consider the following example of 3 javascript files:

```
/** myclass.js **/
import jQuery from 'jQuery';

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.property = null;
        jQuery('#test').data('myClass', this);
    }

    testMethod() {
       return null;
    }
}

export default MyClass;
```

```
/** file.js **/
import MyClass from './myclass.js';

new MyClass();

export default null;
```

```
/** index.js **/
import './file.js';
import jQuery from 'jQuery';

let myValue = jQuery('#test').data('myClass');
```

What I would like to achieve, is to get property and method auto suggestion from my IDE on the `myValue` variable. I know (I mean I presume) that automatically, there is no way for the IDE to know what I stored in the data variable of `jQuery`, but what kind of type hint should I provide before `myValue` to tell the IDE, that it should be an instance of `MyClass`?

If in `index.js` I also import `myclass.js` with the definition of the class, I was able to achieve my result, by type hinting before the variable with the following `jsdoc` comment:

```
 /** @type {MyClass} */
```

But this line only works if I also imported the definition in the current scope. Is there any way to either:

1. achieve suggestions automatically, without manually type hinting?
2. or if that is not possible, type hint, without manually importing the definition beforehand?

I am using `Visual Studio Code v1.46.1` and I have the `ESLint v2.1.5` extension installed on it.

**EDIT:** After trying to create a `jsconfig.json` file in my root folder, with the following options:

```
{
   "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and modifying my `index.js` by adding this `jsdoc` comment, I am still getting no autosuggestions by VSCode:

```
/** @type {MyClass} */
```

I've tried adding the above comment both above, and below the line, where I fetch the data from the `jQuery` element.

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, basically, it looks like that my IntelliSense "breaks" when I am trying to export something from a file. Could this be a VSCode issue?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45836847/1244884

Comment: @customcommander I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Basically, what you are suggesting there, is that add a `@typedef` in the same file where I define my `class`, and set the configuration of `vscode`, and it should fetch all typedefs in my workspace? Even if I would manage to get that to work, wouldn't I be obligated, to define all the implemented methods in a separate file for the class?

Comment: The `@typedef` tag is irrelevant in your case but perhaps the `jsconfig.json` file is useful?

Comment: @customcommander even with include set, I can not get IntelliSense to show me suggestion by typehinting the variable. Maybe I am doing something wrong still, as the name of my class doesn't show up in the autosuggestions of the valid types neither. Should I do anything else, except creating the `jsconfig.json` file? I updated my question with the way I try to use `@type`, maybe I have a problem there?

Comment: @customcommander additionally, I've noticed, that if I add the above `jsconfig.json` file to my project, autosuggestions on import paths also dissapear. (obviously, my real project is a bit bigger then the example above, with a `node_modules` folder also, and until now, when I tried to import something, `vscode` was showing the `node_modules` folder contents as the root, and provided me with suggestions on the folder structure)